# How to convert dollar amounts between years?

Tags: usd-us-dollar

If something cost 17 million USD in 1994 how to I figure out what it would have cost in 2000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inflation counter on [THIS WEBSITE](https://www.officialdata.org/) will help you find the answer you are looking for.

In case you don't want to click through to the link:

> $17,000,000 in the year 1994 is equivalent in purchasing power to $19,753,036.44 in 2000, a difference of $2,753,036.44 over 6 years.

This is obviously the easiest way to do it. To do it yourself you need to know the inflation rate of every year from 1994 to 2000. Here, you can see that the annualized average rate of inflation over that period was 2.699%. The link I provided will also provide data fro each year you are looking for if you want to try the math yourself.

It's worth noting that this sort of thing would be very easy to build into an Excel sheet where you can input your own figures and get the same result. This may be useful if you are constantly looking at historical dollar values.

Comment: I found a few sites that will give me the answer, but I want to know how to figure it out on my own.

Comment: Ahh, I see on your link it tells me the formula. Thank you